# "The" before adjectives

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I'm a bit confused about this.

Which example is the right one?

From all the fellow writers, who was the best?

From all fellow writers, who was the best?

Is there a reason why "the" should be used before the adjective in this case? Is there a reason for it not to be there? Thanks.

Comment: Who are the fellow writers? Is it all other writers everywhere or a particular subset?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't actually about "the" before adjectives: it is about **plural articles**.

Both examples are grammatically correct, though the first one is more likely to be what you mean. The first example uses the **definite** article "the" to indicate a *specific* set of fellow writers (possibly ones that were introduced before). The second uses the **indefinite** 'zero' article (ie no article) to indicate an *arbitrary* set of fellow writers (in this case, all possible ones, not necessarily connected to any specific person). A third meaning, also using no article, is the **generic** sense, as in the sentence "Fellow writers tend to criticise"